# React Native - Issue with ENV configurations in Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-config

I have configured ENVs using `react-native-config` package. I have 3 different ENVs which I have defined in `app/build.gradle`

This is defined as below -

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    debug: ".env.dev",
    stagingRelease: ".env.staging",
    prodRelease: ".env.prod",
]
```

Now when I run `npx react-native run-android --variant=prodRelease`. It is breaking with error - `Task 'installProdRelease' not found in project ':app'.`

How can I make it working so that I can run different environments in app ?

Answer (score 0):

The value that is passed to `--variant` option is basically a combination of product flavor and build type. By default there are 2 build types defined - `debug` and `release`. To add flavors like `development`, `staging`, `production`, define them below `buildTypes` in `android/app/build.gradle` -

```
    buildTypes {
        .....
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        production {}
        staging {}
        development {}
    }
```

Now with a configuration like this -

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    developmentdebug: ".env.development",
    developmentrelease: ".env.development",
    stagingdebug: ".env.staging",
    stagingrelease: ".env.staging",
    productiondebug: ".env.production",
    productionrelease: ".env.production",
]

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
```

you can now build like you wanted -

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=stagingdebug
npx react-native run-android --variant=productionrelease
```

You can read more about Android build types and flavors here.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

For a similar configuration in iOS, follow this excellent tutorial.
https://www.bigbinary.com/books/learn-react-native/handling-environment-specific-configurations-in-react-native